# Summary statistics for continuous variable by levels of factor variables AND stratified by a second categorical variable

Tags: r, summary

I am trying to generate summary statistics (for a sort of epidemiological Table 1) for a continuous variable (systolic blood pressure, sysbp) by levels of several categorical variables (sex, age category, BMI category, etc), **all stratified by race/ethnicity**, however all the information I find is to create summary tables for a *categorical* outcome by levels of other variables.

Some simplified example data:

```
set.seed(42)
sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
bmicat <- sample(c("<18.5", "18.5-24", "25-29", ">=30"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
smoker_ever <- sample(c("Ever", "Never"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
agecat <- sample(c("<25", "25-44", "45-64", ">=65"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
race_ethnicity <- sample(c("African", "Hispanic/Latino", "Asian"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
sysbp <- rnorm(n=100, mean=140, sd=10)

bio <- data.frame(sex, bmicat, agecat, smoker_ever, race_ethnicity, sysbp)
```

So far all I've come up with is manually calculating each mean and sd with stat.desc like this for each combination of sex/age category/BMI category/smoking status + race/ethnicity like this:

```
stat.desc(bio$sysbp[bio$sex == 'Male' & bio$race_ethnicity == 'Hispanic/Latino'], basic = T)
```

and manually entering the resulting mean and sd into my table, but this is obviously very inefficient.
So the goal is to have a table with columns for each race/ethnicity category and rows for each of the categorical variables listed above, with the summary measures being for **sysbp** of the entries for each combination of categorical variable level + race/ethnicity category (as well as a "total/overall" column and row). Is there any way to do this simply?

Comment: This will get you the values for each combination: `aggregate(sysbp~., bio, function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))`.  You will still need to pick a package that produces formatted tables to get the arrangement you want. You will need to use `aggregate` for other combinations, eg. sex or age.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am, cyl) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), list(m = mean, s = sd))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c("am", "cyl"), names_to = c("variable", ".value"), names_pattern="(.*)_([ms])$")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'am'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 54 × 5
#> # Groups:   am [2]
#>       am   cyl variable      m      s
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     0     4 mpg       22.9   1.45 
#>  2     0     4 disp     136.   14.0  
#>  3     0     4 hp        84.7  19.7  
#>  4     0     4 drat       3.77  0.13 
#>  5     0     4 wt         2.94  0.408
#>  6     0     4 qsec      21.0   1.67 
#>  7     0     4 vs         1     0    
#>  8     0     4 gear       3.67  0.577
#>  9     0     4 carb       1.67  0.577
#> 10     0     6 mpg       19.1   1.63 
#> # … with 44 more rows
#> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>